# Shell Programming - How do I loop through a list and process N at a time?

Tags: list, shell, loops

I am trying to read though a list and I want to read 25 at a time in the list then sleep for 5 seconds then keep reading 25 at a time until I exhaust the list.

This is what I'm doing right now, but I start too many ssh sessions at the same time. I want to be able to run 25, sleep for 5 seconds, run 25 more until the list has been exhausted.

```
cat ctrlnodes.txt |\
while read N
do
ssh -n $N "/var/opt/OV/bin/instrumentation/agent_health.sh" &
done
```

Comment: What shell? A list of what? What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Which shell language are you scripting in?

Comment: Sorry, bash is what I'm using. I know how to process a simple list and do something for each line, but I don't know how to do it 25 lines at a time.

Comment: What's the form of the list? Some text file? Give some more info what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer

```
counter=0
while read N; do
   ((counter++))
   ssh -n $N "/var/opt/OV/bin/instrumentation/agent_health.sh" &
   [[ $(($counter % 25)) = 0 ]] && sleep 5
done <ctrlnodes.txt
```

#### Explanation

First, a counter needs to be initialized before the loop and incremented through each iteration; this allows the script to test whether it's on an iteration that's evenly divisible by `25`.

Second, you need to change the `cat` pipe of your text file to `while` to a direct input redirection on `done`; when you use the former a subshell is created and `$counter` will be out of scope and won't increment properly.

Finally, what probably needs the most explanation is the evenly-divisible test itself:

```
[[ $(($counter % 25)) = 0 ]] && sleep 5
```

What this does is perform a test of whether modulus `25` of the counter is zero. (i.e., `$counter` is evenly divisible by `25`) If it is then the test's exit value is true, so the 'and' (`&&`) can continue on to the `sleep` command; if the modulus value is non-zero then the `&&` won't continue since the test will have a false exit value.

A one-liner test of the concept:

```
seq 1 100 >numbers.txt && counter=0 && while read N; do ((counter++)); echo $N; [[ $(($counter % 25)) = 0 ]] && echo -n sleeping... && sleep 5 && echo; done <numbers.txt
```

What you should see is blocks of 25 numbers, a "sleeping..." line with a 5 second pause, until it's gone through all 1..100.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(seq 1 100 )
do

    for j in $(seq 1 25)
    do
    # suppose you have an array
        echo ${your_list[i]}
    done

    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: No need to use `seq` when the limits are known, use `{1..25}` instead

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Let's say that my list is called "nodes" and I want to read it and echo the nodes out 25 at a time until I process all of them. Sorry for needing the hand holding. I have done this in a very inefficient way in the past using temp files and I don't want to keep using bad examples.

Comment: @sbursik - update your question with what you really are trying to do. Example code is the best!

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now, but I start too many ssh sessions at the same time. I want to be able to run 25, sleep for 5 seconds, run 25 more until the list has been exhausted.


    `cat ctrlnodes.txt |\
    while read N
    do
    ssh -n $N "/var/opt/OV/bin/instrumentation/agent_health.sh &
    done`

Comment: @sbursik - update your question instead of giving us the info in a comment :-)

Comment: I'm a total newb here. Embarrassing. I'll post what I'm doing in a moment

Comment: @sbursik - no worries. See my answer; hopefully I understood you correctly, if not, drop me a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Lets create a file with one integer/row, 100 rows:

```
$ seq 1 100 > data
```

Using the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=1
while read N
do
    # here you call your ssh
    if [ $((n % 25)) -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Spawned 25 subprocesses, waiting..."
        echo $n, $N
        # wait for all subprocesses to finish before continuing
        # Replace 'wait' with 'sleep 5' if that's desired
        wait
    fi
    ((n+=1))
done < data
```

output:

```
$ ./s.sh 
Spawned 25 subprocesses, waiting...
25, 25
Spawned 25 subprocesses, waiting...
50, 50
Spawned 25 subprocesses, waiting...
75, 75
Spawned 25 subprocesses, waiting...
100, 100
```

Comment: Perfect! I get what you're doing and this works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Welcome to SO! Keep them questions coming